# Dedicate 1 ethernet port on Mac Pro to internal backup volume?

Tags: mac-pro, ethernet, backup

Is this possible? I'm using a Mac Pro as a home (Lion) server, connected via ethernet to a gigabit switch. One internal drive is reserved for network backups from local users via Time Machine. All running Lion. Can I use the 2nd (currently redundant) ethernet port exclusively for backups to the internal drive, and so save the other port for other network traffic / file serving?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, assign a static IP to the 2nd port, create a DNS record pointing to that IP, then configure the remote Macs to use the DNS name.